# Azure Cosmosdb Mongo API compatibility with Collation queries, when enabling the MongoDB 3.4 wire protocol Preview feature

Tags: azure

Does the Preview feature of Azure Cosmosdb MongoDB, "3.4 wire protocol support" support [collations](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/collation/) which is a feature since MongoDB version 3.4. It is not clear for me after going through this [mongodb-feature-support](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/mongodb-feature-support#database-commands) doc